# Encode an executable file

Tags: c++, encoding, ascii

I want to Encode and Decode an executable file

The problem is about NULL

The file content is MZ(NULL) so the binary code  will be

```
01001101 01011010 00000000
```

The output should should be:

```
4d (for M -> 0100 1101) 

5a(for Z -> 0101 1010) and 

00(for NULL -> 0000 0000)
```

In hexadecimal:

```
346435610000
```

but it is: `346435613930`

[image]

here is my code:

```
    CHAR* WriteBuffer = NULL;
BYTE *ReadBuffer = NULL;
DWORD fSize = 0;
OVERLAPPED ol = {0};
BYTE AsciiTable[] = {0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0xE, 0xF};
int a = 0;
//...
ReadFile(hndlRead, *ReadBuffer, *fSize, NULL, &ol);

for(DWORD i=0; i< fSize; i++)
{
    a = ReadBuffer[i]& 0xf0;

    if (a > 15)
    {
        a = a / 16;
    }
    wsprintfA(WriteBuffer, "%s%x", WriteBuffer, AsciiTable[a]);
    a = ReadBuffer[i] & 0x0f;
    wsprintfA(WriteBuffer, "%s%x", WriteBuffer, AsciiTable[a]);
}
```

Edit / Decode:

I wish to use AsciiTable for Decode, but I couldn't so I decode in this form:

```
//....
int a = 0;
for(DWORD i=0; i<dwFileSize; i++)
{
    sscanf_s((CHAR*)ReadBuffer + i*2 ,"%02x" , &a);             
    wsprintfA(szWriteBuffer, "%s%c", szWriteBuffer, a);
}
```

Comment: You have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you first dereference the `NULL` pointer in `ReadBuffer`, then secondly try to use a single `BYTE` as an address to write to. Same thing with `fSize`. You need to go back to a simpler pointer tutorial and learn how to handle pointers thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you allocate enough buffer and clear it before write to WriteBuffer.

Performance issue: your algorithm is O(n^2), best use this one, is O(n):

```
CHAR AsciiTable[] = '0123456789ABCDEF';

DWORD j=0;
for(DWORD i=0; i< fSize; i++)
{
    WriteBuffer[j++]=AsciiTable[ReadBuffer[i]>>4];
    WriteBuffer[j++]=AsciiTable[ReadBuffer[i]&0x0f];
}
```

UPDATE

Sorry, I misunderstand your question. You want to decode the NULL value (byte value 0) to exactly 2 consecutive 0's values. In this case, try this:

```
DWORD j=0;
for(DWORD i=0; i< fSize; i++)
{
    if (ReadBuffer[i])
    {
        WriteBuffer[j++]=AsciiTable[ReadBuffer[i]>>4];
        WriteBuffer[j++]=AsciiTable[ReadBuffer[i]&0x0f];
    }
    else 
    {
        WriteBuffer[j++]=WriteBuffer[j++]=0;
    }
}
```

UPDATE II: the decoder code

As asked, this is the decode code in O(n) instead of the O(n^2) version written.

```
#define ASCII2BYTE(V) (((V)>'9')?(V)-'A':(V-'9')

for (DWORD i=0;i<dwFileSize;i+=2)
{
    szWriteBuffer[i>>1]=(ASCII2BYTE(ReadBuffer[i])<<4)+ASCII2BYTE(ReadBuffer[i+1]);
}
```

UPDATE III: how works the ASCII2BYTE Macro (as requested)

To convert 4D5A, try to execute the decoding code with ReadBuffer="4D5A", dwFileSize=4; every pair of chars are taken, then the first is the Most Significant Nibble (=4 bit) and is converted from ASCII to decimal ('4'-->4), than the second char 'D' is converted to the Least Significant Nibble, ('D'-->12), than (4<<4)+12 = 76, that is exactly the ascii code for 'M'. Same for 5A

Comment: thank you, this algorithm  is better but it has the same problem with NULL / I have problem in Decoding

Comment: post the decode code, so we can understand better the problem. if fSize is correct, the code I provide is ok.. so in the example you provides, check if fSize is equal to 3 (bytes). When you decode, you will have to decode a buffer of 3*2=6 bytes

Comment: Thank you, I post my decode code, but it doesn't work correctly too, and why does it take too much time for a 100kb .exe file, is there a faster way for encode and decode?

Comment: You're welcome. Your code has the same performance issue of the encoder, you use an "append" technique that has O(n^2) complexity. Code and decoding are very similar, take my encoder code as an example and write down the decoder. It's very easy if you think how I implement the encoder.

Comment: I write the decoder part too, take a look. Accept the answer if you like it

Comment: what is `#define ASCII2BYTE(V) (((V)>'9')?(V)-'A':(V-'9')`, I don't understand it

Comment: This is a macro definition. Convert the V ASCII value from '0'..'9'-'A'..'F' to 0..15 value, using the ? operator; that's a ternary operator, look at this for an explanation: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/14631/

Comment: Something like this?
`INT A(int b)
{
 if (b > '9')
 {
  return b - 'A';
 }
 else
 {
  return b - '9';
 }
}`
but I couldn't return `MZ` form `4D5A` with this code! :(

Comment: See the Update III. Please try to execute the code.